# How to print Hello World without semicolon in Java?

Tags: java, printf, println

Can someone explain to me why printf works but println does not work?

```
if (System.out.printf("Hello World") == null);


if (System.out.println("Hello World") == null);
```

Comment: `println` is `void`, so you can't compare its "return value" to something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`println` has a `void` return type, so you can't compare it to `null` (or to anything else).

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

`printf` returns a `PrintStream` instance, allowing you to compare it to `null` (though I see no reason why you'd want to do that, since it would never return `null`).

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args) {
    return format(format, args);
}
```

Comment: *Clarification (terminology):* `printf` doesn't return the `PrintStream` for the *purpose* of being compared to `null`, it does it for the purpose of allowing method chaining. The fact that it returns an object makes it *possible* for you to compare it to `null`. The phrase "so you can compare it to `null`" can be read either way, and should be rephrased to clarify the intended meaning.

Comment: @Andreas I had thought similarly when I read it, but checked my pedantry. Proposed a minor rewording.